# Collapse array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array `int[][] r = new int[10][1000]`

I want to remove any null values in the array and collapse it.

so if the array is `{{5,3,null,2,null,80,90,348,38,null,...},...}`

I want it to be `{{5,3,2,80,90,348,38,...},...}` (the length is changed as well)

I'm not looking for code or for you to do it for me, but can you point me in the right direction? I searched and couldn't find anything like this.

Comment: You'd need to create new arrays (and decide how to handle situations where the lengths might be different if that's a possibility) and filter.

Comment: you dont need to search it, try to understand what you need to do.

Comment: For a pointer, check out System.arraycopy() and Arrays.copyOf().

Comment: can't have nulls in int[]. if you want nulls you'll have to use the Integer wrapper, e.g., Integer[][] r = new Integer[10][1000];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup -

1. iterate the array and count the non-null elements
2. declare a new array with a size found in (1), and add to it only non-null elements.

btw, you can't have `null` elements in `int` array

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's easy:

```
int[][] uncollapsed = ...;
int[][] collapsed = uncollapsed;
```

An array of primitives (including `int[]`) can't contain null, so there's not much work you have to do.

If there's a more correct question you want to ask I suggest you edit your question, but at a glance I'd say that arrays are a poor data type choice if you want to do removals like this.  Consider a collections interface, like `List`.

Answer (score 0):

At insertion time:

```
if (val == null) skip();
```

At a later time:

```
for(Element el: elementList) {

  if (el == null)  remove();

}
```

In a nutshell...